# objdump not working on ELF 64-bit x86-64,

Tags: c, binutils

I have a 64bits ELF object code from the Tiny C compiler. I can't get gobjdump to show the disassembled code. I'm using OS X 10.10.5.

```
$ file hello.o 
hello.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
$ gobjdump -d hello.o
gobjdump: hello.o: File format not recognized

$ greadelf -h hello.o
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              REL (Relocatable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          228 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         0
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         7
  Section header string table index: 6
```

Extra Information:

```
$uname -a
Darwin Nawals-MacBook-Air.local 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: 

Tue Sep  1 21:23:09 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.50.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ gobjdump -i
BFD header file version (GNU Binutils) 2.24
mach-o-x86-64
mach-o-i386
mach-o-le
mach-o-be
mach-o-fat
pef
pef-xlib
sym
srec
symbolsrec
verilog
tekhex
binary
ihex
```

I don't understand why stack overflow think my question is mostly code - I want to give as much information as possible to help people answer. I didn't think pastebin et al. were encouraged here.

Comment: The answer is simple. Your `gobjdump` was compiled with support for Mac OS X's Mach-O binary format _only_. Your `gobjdump` build does not support parsing ELF.

Comment: The native object file format on OSX is Mach-O, not ELF, so it's not surprising that it doesn't support ELF.

Comment: I kinda thought that might be it - is there a way to compile binutils to support elf on OS X? I don't want to run the code, just compile it with tcc and then disassemble it.

Comment: See if tcc has an option to produce assembly output directly.

Comment: Unfortunately, TCC is quite proud of producing the object code without outputting assembly for later assembling. But I managed to compile a binutils for elf64, as shown in a comment below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the available output formats, per the man page are as follows:

```
  -Wl,--oformat,fmt
       Use fmt as output format. The supported output formats are:

       "elf32-i386"
           ELF output format (default)

       "binary"
           Binary image (only for executable output)

       "coff"
           COFF output format (only for executable output for TMS320C67xx
           target)
```

So, regardless of the online claim that the x86-64 is supported, the latest version does not support x86-64 output for the object file

Comment: Thanks! I had to compile binutils specifically for it, with a target=x86_64-elf for it to work.